# Android Dialog Fragment wont change its layout when device is rotated

Tags: android, rotation, dialogfragment

I've a DialogFragment  and when the device is rotated it won't change its layout from portrait to landscape. Must dismiss the dialog and reoprn it after I rotated the device.

Comment: please post your code for creating the dialog and your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Are you handling orientation changes yourself? Do you have something like `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` in your manifest file?